# Calling functions and returning values

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++.I have a function which returns some parameters that i need ,to use in  the rest of my program.I am trying to access that function within another class.I am confused with the way i can do it...Can anyone please help me..?

Following is my code :

```
 void SampleProgram :: myFunction()
   {
         string sInput;
         GetInfo  getInfo(sInput);  //creating instance of the class containing the function

            string sSw="";
       string sName="ram";
       string sList="list";

           getInfo.getRequiredInfo(sSw,sName,sList); //calling the function

    }
```

How can i access the output parameters of getRequiredInfo() ..?and save it if the ouput parameters are as following :string name,int status
Please help me...

Comment: Its not clear what you want to do here. Whar are the output parameters of `getRequiredInfo` and what do you mean by saving it?

Comment: My getRequiredInfo() function accepts three input parameters and returns 2 output parameters.I need to access those two parameters in my calling function myFunction()..how can i  do it..?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to show us the declaration of getRequiredInfo(), but presumably it's something like

```
X result = getInfo.getRequiredInfo(sSw,sName,sList);
```

We don't know what *X* is without seeing that declaration.

Answer (score 0):

In case `getRequiredInfo` get the **address** of the strings, try this:

```
getInfo.getRequiredInfo(&sSw, &sName, &sList);
```

Now the function can change the value of the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can able to return single value in function.

so You can create struct containing string and int and return that as the result.

```
    struct
    {
           string name;
            int    k;
    }result;
    result r = getInfo.getRequiredInfo(sSw,sName,sList); //calling the function
```

you can save the output parameters like these:

```
   string _name;
   int       nk;

   _name = r.name;
   nk    = r.k;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be return a `pair<string,int>` from the function. So your function signarutre would be `pair<string,int> getRequiredInfo(const string& s1, const string& s2, constr string& s3);`. You can then access the `string` and `int` part usinf `first` and `second` members of the `pair`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though `getRequiredInfo` has the behaviour of both *reading from* and *writing to* some of the parameters you've passed in.

In C++, unlike in C#, there's no way to specify that a function should, or must, change the value of a given parameter. Indeed, if you have defined your function like this:

```
void GetInfo::getRequiredInfo(string a, string b, string c);
```

then all three parameters will be passed *by value* meaning any changes made to them inside the function will be changing *copies* of those objects, rather than the objects themselves.

As other contributors have suggested, if you really want to *change* the parameters you passed in, you could either do so by passing references:

```
void GetInfo::getRequiredInfo(string a, string& b, string& c);
```

or (more typically) by passing pointers:

```
void GetInfo::getRequiredInfo(string a, string* b, string* c);
```

However, if you want your function to simply read the parameters and return a value (which is the more accepted term for what you're calling 'output parameters') then you have to express your tuple of "name + status" as a single value.

You could use the built in `pair` template as someone else just suggested:

```
pair<string,int> getRequiredInfo(string a, string b, string c);
```

Or you could define your own struct to do it, like someone else suggested:

```
struct NameAndStatus
{
    string name;
    int status;
};

NameAndStatus getRequiredInfo(string a, string b, string c);
```